# Android: how to find size of viewable screen?

Tags: android

I was going to use `Display.getWidth()` x `Display.getHeight()`, but the documentation for getHeight() notes:

`Returns the raw height of the display, in pixels. Note that this should not generally be used for computing layouts, since a device will typically have screen decoration (such as a status bar) along the edges of the display that reduce the amount of application space available from the raw size returned here. This value is adjusted for you based on the current rotation of the display`.

So, what is it reliable to do `Display.getWidth()` x `Display.getHeight() - statusHeight`?  Or is there a more formal way to find the viewable rectangle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`View#getWidth()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getWidth%28%29) and [`View#getHeight()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getHeight%28%29) on the relevant [`View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) instance after layout is complete. If you are using a [`SurfaceView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) you can also use the values supplied to you by the [`surfaceChanged`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback.html#surfaceChanged%28android.view.SurfaceHolder,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) callback.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you're trying to do. If you are creating a SurfaceView which fills the screen, you should implement `SurfaceHolder.Callback` and find out the size when `surfaceChanged()` is called. If you're creating your own view, then you determine your size in the `onMeasure()` method.

Comment: Let's say I wanted to create a Bitmap of the exact same size of the screen.  And would need the screen dimensions...

Comment: You don't necessarily have control over the entirety of the screen. (e.g. Android 3.0 tablets do not allow applications to hide the system bar and take over that screen space.) As a result it is likely that you want the size of your view, not the size of the screen.

Comment: Size of the screen is what you get thorugh `Display` class, but you said it doesn't suit you. The problem is there shouldn't even necessary be a visible status bar. So what you actually need is the size of some View. You have to find this view and find out its dimensions.